# PHP SQL Database for saving scores

Tags: php, sql, database

I've got a database setup for scores, each score is out of 100 and i need to be able to save more than one value and output it so that a user can see it. I have no idea however how to save the scores; my knowledge of php is limited and i only know how to save one value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: With no code and no database schema, it'll be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Basically, the database just has (name, scores). I want the user to be able to keep adding scores but with their name, but i have no idea how to set the database up to do that. I've not actually coded anything as of yet.

Comment: Have you thought about separate "scores" and "users" tables?

Comment: I'd be quiet happy doing that; give each one an id? But then i'd have to add each score as a new field? And give it the same ID as the one in the users table?

Comment: I generally give tables in my databases an ID field, but it's not necessary; just add a foreign key in scores that references a user.

Comment: What would i need to do about then submitting the values from a form to SQL database? - For example:

Danny 97 95 94 96 95 94

Comment: You should update your question to contain all your requirements you've come up with in comments.  As it is, there is no way for someone to answer your question without simply writing the code for you.  It sounds like you should read more on using databases ("my knowledge of php is limited and I only know how to save one value").

Comment: Please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/q/43157339/7801723

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think you could get by with something like this:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO scores(name, score) VALUES ('John', 100),('John', 75),('Bob', 68)");
```

Or

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO scores(name, score) VALUES ('John', 100)");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO scores(name, score) VALUES ('John', 75)");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO scores(name, score) VALUES ('Bob', 68)");
```

If you wanted a specific users score you could do:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name='John'");
```

If you wanted a list of users:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT name FROM scores GROUP BY name");
```

Comment: He's going to have to make sure that his scores table has an ID field, or else there will be a problem if John gets another 75.

Comment: And if John changes his name to something else? He loses all his score history? Or if there are two Johns? Not best practice database scheme here.

Comment: Only if he ever needs to modify a row. You can insert and select the duplicates just fine but I would agree ids would probably be a good thing.

Comment: I understand how this would work but my problem now is; i have no idea how to do it within the PHP

Comment: You don't understand how to do the sql insert or other things like get a form submission? It might be best to either insert more code into your question or close this question and start a new one

Comment: I've sorted that part out now; i'm just trying to get my head round linking the two tables

Comment: With PHP, you need to make a connection to the database, then initiate a SQL (or MySQL) call to the data you want and place the retrieved data into a variable/array you can use elsewhere, then close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is in this case is to have 2 tables: one for names, one for scores. Then associate them with a joining table. This way your database is "normalized" and won't have repeating data whenever "John" enters his score of "95" more than once.  Your two tables will need an ID field (ID, Name) and (ID, Score), with a third table called something like "Names_Scores" (Name_ID, Score_ID).  Then use joining queries to match up what Name ID has what Score ID, and list them for the user when they log in.

Comment: Right; i've got two tables now. Name and Scores. Name has two fields (uid and name), scores also has two (uid and scores) how do i link the UID so that they are both the same in each table? Im using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using "UID" to mean User ID?  If so, you're confusing things here.  In your first table, make it (UserID, Name), and then make the UserID field a PRIMARY KEY. In your 2nd table (ScoreID, Scores), also making ID a PK field. Then make a third table (UserID,ScoreID) ...this will hold the matching IDs that joins the other two tables.

Comment: This answer require three tables. The third table is the linking table. So lets say you have 1,John|2,Bob in the Name table and 1,75|2,80 in the score table. You would have 1,1 and 2,2 in the linking table (Names_Scores). That would mean John has a score of 75 and Bob 80. If you then added a third name Sue and she had a score of 75 in the linking table there would be another row 3,1

Comment: I've changed all the UID to id instead; do they need to be auto_number or just int? And i've created the third table but do not know how to link them?

Comment: @DannyHickerz - I may have misunderstood slightly, but I was assuming the scores would be set values such as a series of numbers like 60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100. If that's the case, then definitely 3 tables are required, however if the values vary every time (such as 62.5,73.6,95,82,etc.) then you can do this with only 2 tables by making your Scores table have two fields (UID, Score).  Then your `SELECT` query will match `UID`s between the 2 tables, grabbing all scores that match the requested UID.

Comment: @GregR. It's not my question and it's pretty light on details. I may have misunderstood as well I was just clarifying how I thought your answer would work with an example.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you need to make a connection to the database, then initiate a SQL (or MySQL) call to the data you want and place the retrieved data into a variable/array you can use elsewhere, then close the connection.

Example:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("[hostname]", "[username]", "[password]");
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Users.UID, Users.Name, Scores.Score FROM Users, Scores WHERE Users.UID = Scores.UID GROUP BY Users.UID, Scores.Score") or die(mysql_error());

echo $result;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```